# RTNETLINK: Device or resource busy - DELL 2950

Tags: networking, centos, centos6, linux-networking, eth0

I cant start second NIC on Dell Poweredge 2950, OMSA installed, the NIC cards is BCM5708C ,version of Operating System Centos 6.7.

The first card worling correctly

```
[root@alfa ~]# ifup eth1
RTNETLINK answers: Device or resource busy
Failed to bring up eth1.
```

-

```
[root@alfa ~]# uname -a
Linux alfa.uskonnen.net 2.6.32-573.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Aug 13 22:55:16 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

-

```
[root@alfa ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1
DEVICE=eth1
BOOTPROTO=static
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
UUID="be0b2777-dc5c-421b-b3be-d0f5664f603f"
IPADDR=123.123.123.49
NETMASK=255.255.255.224
DNS1=1.1.1.1
DNS2=2.2.2.2.2
GATEWAY=123.123.123.62
TYPE=Ethernet
HWADDR=00:1a:a0:0d:3a:9c
```

-

```
cat /var/log/messages:
alfa kernel: bnx2 0000:09:00.0: firmware: requesting bnx2/bnx2-mips-06-6.2.3.fw
alfa kernel: bnx2 0000:09:00.0: firmware: requesting bnx2/bnx2-rv2p-06-6.0.15.fw
alfa kernel: bnx2: fw sync timeout, reset code = 5030024
alfa kernel: bnx2 0000:09:00.0: eth1: <--- start MCP states dump --->
alfa kernel: bnx2 0000:09:00.0: eth1: DEBUG: MCP_STATE_P0[00000106] MCP_STATE_P1[dffdffff]
alfa kernel: bnx2 0000:09:00.0: eth1: DEBUG: MCP mode[0000b800] state[80004000] evt_mask[00000500]
alfa kernel: bnx2 0000:09:00.0: eth1: DEBUG: pc[08006b88] pc[08006b88] instr[1440fffb]
alfa kernel: bnx2 0000:09:00.0: eth1: DEBUG: shmem states:
alfa kernel: bnx2 0000:09:00.0: eth1: DEBUG: drv_mb[05030024] fw_mb[00000023] link_status[0000f06b] drv_pulse_mb[000000$
alfa kernel: bnx2 0000:09:00.0: eth1: DEBUG: dev_info_signature[44564905] reset_type[01005254] condition[00000106]
alfa kernel: bnx2 0000:09:00.0: eth1: DEBUG: 000001c0: 01005254 4253800a 00000106 d7ffffff
alfa kernel: bnx2 0000:09:00.0: eth1: DEBUG: 000003cc: 44444444 44444444 44444444 00000a28
alfa kernel: bnx2 0000:09:00.0: eth1: DEBUG: 000003dc: 0004ffff 00000000 00000000 00000000
alfa kernel: bnx2 0000:09:00.0: eth1: DEBUG: 000003ec: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00a27657
alfa kernel: bnx2 0000:09:00.0: eth1: DEBUG: 0x3fc[0000ffff]
alfa kernel: bnx2 0000:09:00.0: eth1: <--- end MCP states dump --->
alfa /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup-eth: Failed to bring up eth1.
```

How it can be fixed? Please help

Comment: the output of `ip link` or `ip addr` would be useful.  in the meantime, i can see one error in your `ifcfg-eth1` file:  `DNS2=2.2.2.2.2` should actually only have four octets, not five.  so it should read `DNS2=2.2.2.2`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation, although with different hardware.  The problem turned out to be a firmware issue that I resolved by re-flashing the NIC.  The question asks about Broadcom NICs on a Dell system, but my case is with Intel NICs on an Intel system.  I'm not certain if there is any non-volatile portion of the firmware on Broadcom NICs or not, so this method might not have a similar method available for that system.

In my case, I had an Intel server board (S2600ST) with onboard Intel NICs.  The NICs worked fine for PXE booting, and for handling out-of-band IPMI.  The OS could even *see* the NICs... ifconfig would list the interfaces, but upon trying to bring the interface up, it would give the same error:

```
RTNETLINK answers: Device or resource busy
```

First, I tried to flash the BIOS/BMC/FRU.  That didn't change the behavior, and the problem persisted.  This would still be a good first step to take for most systems.

Next, I tried reflashing the NIC itself.   Intel NICs need to be flashed to enable PXE booting and other preboot option ROMs.  Knowing this, I installed Intel's [bootutil](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005790/software/manageability-products.html) and ran it.  It listed every NIC in the system, after which I ran it with the the option to enable the PXE option rom:

```
./bootutil64e -FLASHENABLE -NIC=1
```

Running this flashes the entire NIC firmware, and doesn't just change a setting in a small nvram region.  So even though I didn't change anything (as the PXE option rom was already installed/enabled), it reflashed the firmware.

Now a reboot is required.  I rebooted the system, and the OS could now bring up the interface without errors, as well as use the NIC.